# How to detect that an operation on a folder won't be able to complete before starting said operation, from Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

If we want to move or delete a folder, but some of its contained files are currently being used, the operation will likely fail after it has already started, and the folder could be left in a half-way, "corrupt" state.

Is there a fast way to detect in advance that this will happen to avoid starting the operation?

Caveat: I realize that if we perform the check beforehand, it might pass, but a file might start being used during the operation. Maybe in that case the solution would be to restore the folder's contents as they were before the operation started.

Comment: if operations on folder is made by another program, maybe just do a try delete in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a folder then there are multiple ways to do it like some example

1. You can check if a folder has a handle on it using the next function - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564444/15358800)
2. Try renaming under exception - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256114/15358800)
3. Sometimes permission errors may leads to terminate the opertion if folder is being opened or used by other process in such cases os module does have the [os.access](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access) function to check access